# How to get rid of dash error on Delphi MySQL query?

Tags: delphi

I am doing a SQL query on delphi like the one below:

```
    qryPessoas.Open('SELECT * FROM pessoas_login ' +
      'JOIN pessoas ' +
        'ON pessoas.id = pessoas_login.id_pessoa ' +
      'WHERE cpf = 009.052.291-50');
```

I am looking for a `cpf` column value which is `009.052.291-50`.

However I get a `MySQL syntax error on '.291-50'`

The problem is the dash (-), I tried to search for `009.052.29150` and it works perfectly.

**Question**

So, is there a way to make this search with the dash? or is it better to not store data with dashes in the Database?

Comment: Try with quotes on that string (e.i `'WHERE cpf = "009.052.291-50"'`)

Comment: And for the future, please use parameters even when there is no user input. You never know when are you going to introduce the next SQL injection bug.

Comment: Checkout QuotedStr() in the OLH.